# How to replace script content without manually modification

Tags: javascript

The following snippet seems need to repetitively type the same server host "http://106.232.2.2:3000/"

I wonder if there is any js toolchain  can let me maintain this in more effective way like the example with my expectation. It should be run in pruly js without any backend techniques.

## current version

```
<script src="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/jquery_ujs-38e73f935d8e2feac7f47b8c67317969.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/comment-ce9e9195c9ca532a7968ea39a6e1f67f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/application-52b017a9dbb00790db4e22316964e7d9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<link href="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/css/bootstrap-5c674533b683d85b12a4a4b13ee83e70.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://106.232.2.2:3000/assets/css/mint-admin-78ba3e0ba257aa211af6ecf2ddf7f553.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

## expected version

```
define SERVER_HOST =  http://106.232.2.2:3000
<script src="$SERVER_HOST/assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="$SERVER_HOST/assets/jquery_ujs-38e73f935d8e2feac7f47b8c67317969.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="$SERVER_HOST/assets/comment-ce9e9195c9ca532a7968ea39a6e1f67f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="$SERVER_HOST/assets/application-52b017a9dbb00790db4e22316964e7d9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<link href="$SERVER_HOST/assets/css/bootstrap-5c674533b683d85b12a4a4b13ee83e70.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="$SERVER_HOST/assets/css/mint-admin-78ba3e0ba257aa211af6ecf2ddf7f553.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: How about using DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a bit of a contradiction there:

> I wonder if there is any js toolchain ...
>
> It should be run in pruly js without any backend techniques.

Anyway, you can insert those script andlink tags dynamically:

```
var SERVER_HOST = 'http://106.232.2.2:3000';
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.setAttribute('src', SERVER_HOST + '/assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1');
scriptTag.setAttribute('data-turbolinks-track', 'true');
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: Hi, Does some js tool like require.js or webpack can do this ?

Comment: Those are for handling module dependencies. I'm pretty sure you can accomplish that with properly configuring require.js and requiring the appropriate modules, However you could use the above snippet. Lightweight and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
var baseUrl = 'http://106.232.2.2:3000';

var urlArray = ["/assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1",
                "/assets/jquery_ujs-38e73f935d8e2feac7f47b8c67317969.js?body=1"];
var s;

for(var i = 0 ; i < urlArray.length; i ++) {
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = baseUrl + urlArray[i];
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

**Option 2 (HTML option)**

```
<base href="http://106.232.2.2:3000/">
<script src="assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery_ujs-38e73f935d8e2feac7f47b8c67317969.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="assets/comment-ce9e9195c9ca532a7968ea39a6e1f67f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Comment: i can understand this way, but it seems not so intuitive to do so. but still thx for your suggestion :)

Comment: @newBike Give a try with Option2

Comment: Hi, Does some js tool like require.js or webpack can do this ?